# I'm having trouble with my Visual Basic GUI reflecting code calculations

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiplication

When I enter a quantity of **pens** into the appropriate **text box** and press the **calculate button**, the program does not show the **calculated total price** in the appropriate output **text box**. Visual Studio shows no syntax or build errors.

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim dbltxtPensTotalPrice As Double = CDbl(txtPensQuantity.Text) * 25.55
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is no code there putting the result in the textbox.  You would be better off creating a class or something to hold the data.  You will need them all again to calculate the subtotal, tax and total.  UI controls make terrible variables

Comment: `Dim dbltxtPensTotalPrice As Double = CDbl(txtPensQuantity.Text) * 25.55`  You declare this, set it, and then do nothing with it.  Use Decimal for monetary calculations.

Comment: Additionally, a class and collection of items could allow simple changes (price changes or **Peper** to **Paper**), tax rate etc by just changing the data loaded into the class rather than changing the UI at all.